# Replace similar character with different variables in a string

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, substr

Hi I need to `Replace` a `same` character(occurring at multiple positions) with the `different` variables that are `passed`.
In the following template i need to replace `1st %s` with `var1` and `2nd %s` with `var2`.
Please see the below template for reference.

> "Dear %s,Please be informed that the profile modification request
>   for %s  has been 
>        approved.Kindly click on the following link  to view the details.  <>"

How can i do it in PL/SQL procedure?

For  a time being I am writing the following procedure

```
create or replace procedure replace_string()
is
 var1 number;
 var2 varchar2(1000);
 temp varchar2(2000);

 begin

  select TEMPLATE_BODY  into temp 
    from NOTIFICATIONTMPLT 
   where id=116;--i get above template from this id

   select regexp_count  (temp,' %s' ) into var1 
     from dual;--it select my occurence of %s

  for i in 1..var1
   loop
       SELECT substr (temp,1,INSTR(temp,' %s', 1,i)) into var2 
         FROM DUAL;

      dbms_output.put_line(var2);

  end loop;
 end;
 /
```

The above procedure runs successfully.

```
 Output: 
    Dear
    Dear %s,Please be informed that the profile modification request for
```

In this i do not want the `middle Dear%`. I know the error lies in passing the temp again but what can be done to get rid of this problem.
Also i will pass the variables to be replaced in an object and refer the object items as the loop runs.

Comment: :Your question can be more elaborative ,like you said that var1 is replaced with first occurence of `%s` ,that is ok ,but var2 is replaced with second occurence of `%s` is not happening in the code.Please properly mention the output you want ,it will be better for us to understand the requirement.

Comment: i know it is not happening in the code at present but i will integrate that part after doing the substring

Comment: i am planing to store all the variables in an object or varray..then substring the string and concatenate the variables as the loop goes on .i hope its clear

Comment: :You are making simple requirement complex `select regexp_replace('gaurav%sddd%sd', CHR(37)||'s', :var1,1,:x) from dual` check this replace `var1` with your replacing text and `x` with the occurrence.

Comment: i tried it but the variables to be replaced are coming from the parameters of the procedure which i was thinking to hold in an object and concatenate with the substring

Comment: So why cant you use the above query in procedure ?